# ImportError: No module named bottle. Python3.5.1

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle

**I would like to use python 3.5 with bottle and apache.**

But When I access adapter.wsgi from the browser,

> Internal Server Error

▼error_log

> [error] ImportError: No module named os
>
> [error] ImportError: No module named bottle

---

**app**

▼/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIPythonHome /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3

<FilesMatch \.wsgi$>
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch \.py$>
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</FilesMatch>
```

▼adapter.wsgi

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
dirpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dirpath)
os.chdir(dirpath)
import bottle
import index
application = bottle.default_app()
```

▼index.py

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, run, template
from bottle import TEMPLATE_PATH

@route('/')
def index():
    return "HELLO WORLD!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='hogetest.com', port=80, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

---

**current situation**

```
$ python -V
```

> Python 3.5.1

```
$ which python
```

> alias python='/opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3'
>
> ```
>     /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/bin/python3
> ```

Comment: So are you asking how to delete python 2.6.6 because you don't use it or how to fix the ImportError? Also, it doesn't matter if you have python 2.6.6 and want to use python 3 modules, what matters is which python interpreter u use.

Comment: You do not want to remove the pre-installed system python 2.6, it *well* cause problems

Comment: I would like to use Python 3 module. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WSGIPythonHome` directive is wrong to start with. Try instead using:

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr
```

The argument should be the same as what `sys.prefix` is for the Python installation.

The use of the SCL Python version may cause other complexities though.

If that doesn't alone work, find out what the full path to the `.so` for the Python shared library is and use:

```
LoadFile /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib/libpython3.5.so
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
WSGIPythonHome /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr
```

Change the `LoadFile` directive to match what the full path to the shared library actually was. It could instead used the name `libpython3.5m.so`.

Even that may not work depending on where you got `mod_wsgi.so` file from. If that was from system `mod_wsgi` package, then it will not be compiled against the SCL Python versions. In that case you are going to have to uninstall the system `mod_wsgi` package and compile `mod_wsgi` yourself from source code, preferably using the `pip install` method and then using the config that `mod_wsgi-express module-config` gives. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: I tried answer but Error "Target WSGI script  cannot be loaded as Python module." Finally I redoed everything, I made it with make install python 3.6 successfully.

Answer (score 2):

use this command in your terminal for using python3 as the default for all python related work

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
```

you can use `sudo` at the beginning if permission error occurs